# What Other Terms, Besides "Korban," Mean Sacrifice in Some Form or Another?

Tags: words, korban

As the title says, What Other Terms, Besides "Korban," Mean Sacrifice in Some Form or Another?

I am trying to understand sacrifice better. In English, this one word has narrow and broader meanings, but one essential word. Thus, to start looking deeper into this question, I want to know:

are there any other words for sacrifice in Hebrew (explicitly connected with Judaism, Torah, Tanakh, Talmud, etc.)?

Comment: Too Broad? [15c]

Comment: אשה is a good one to start with. Or זבח

Comment: *Korban* means "mechanism for coming close" more than "sacrifice."

Comment: In order to understanding sacrifice better, I think you're much better off looking into the different *types* of offerings, rather than the different words for generic ones. To that end, maybe start with Masekhet Zevachim?

Comment: [Wiktionary lists thirteen different definitions for _sacrifice_.](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sacrifice) Is there a particular one for which you're seeking equivalents in Hebrew, or is it all of them?

Comment: @DoubleAA. How can I narrow it down? It's a single question?

Comment: @msh210. Just any related to Judaism and its sources. I.e., in English we know the difference between, "he's so sacrificial" and "he sacrificed his cat" because of context (although either, esp. the latter, could have variable meanings). More ambiguous would be the common phrase "he makes daily sacrifices." Does that mean he sacrifices animals daily, gives something up every day, or is selfless, or...? Thus, it would help to have more than one English word. I know very little about Hebrew, but want to learn, and this is a particular subject that interests me.

Comment: I doubt you'll find Judaism-based translations of the baseball sense of _sacrifice_, but let's see what the answers say....

Comment: @IsaacMoses (1) Where is _Qorban_ used in the sense of "mechanism for coming close", but not in the sense of "sacrifice"? (2) Personally, I'd prefer a definition of "that which is brought close". Better yet: "that which is offered".

Comment: @TamirEvan 1) The root *QRB* means various conjugations of "come close" in every context. There is no reason to believe that it doesn't mean this in the case of *qorban*, and no reason to think that the word does mean, precisely, "sacrifice." 2) Perhaps. Whether the *qorban* is something that is brought close or something that brings close is a question for a grammarian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better translation of "korban" is "that which brings one close".  It's not that you're "giving up" something (e.g. an animal from your flock) in some sort of tit-for-tat scheme to balance out a debt or transgression; rather, you bring a *korban* because God commanded it and we want to follow God's commands.

There are several types of *korban*, and you'll sometimes see them used without the word "korban" specifically.  They're enumerated in the early chapters of Sefer Vayikra (Leviticus).  Judaism 101 provides [a good summary](http://www.jewfaq.org/qorbanot.htm), which I'll in turn summarize here:

- עלה Olah: Burnt Offering (wholly consumed)
- זבח שלמים Zebach Sh'lamim: Peace (or Thanksgiving) Offering
- חטאת Chatat: Sin Offering (for unintentional transgressions)
- אשם Asham: Guilt Offering (for uncertain transgressions and certain specific sins)
- מנחה Minchah: Meal Offering (I'm not sure this is always counted specifically as a *korban* but I'll list it anyway)

There's also the special case of the *parah adamah* (the red heifer), explained in Parshat Chukat.

Answer (score 2):

[*Sacrifice* means](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sacrifice) "*(transitive)* To trade (a value of higher worth) for one of lesser worth in order to gain something else valued more such as an ally or business relationship or to avoid an even greater loss; to sell without profit to gain something other than money".

In *Shulchan Aruch*, *Choshen Mishpat* 227:20, it's called "המחליף… מחט בשריון או טלה בסוס".

Comment: Where is the "in order to gain something else valued more ... or to avoid an even greater loss" in your example? Otherwise, it is an example of [trading down](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trade_down) or [at a loss](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/at_a_loss), not of a sacrifice.

Comment: @TamirEvan, _SA_ there says "because he wants… more" which is thus "valued more" (to him, a gain of "something other than money").

Answer (score 0):

Mesiras neffesh is a common term term used in the context of someone performing an act where colloquial English would use sacrifice.

I.E. He raised his children with mesiras nefesh. In English the phrase would be: He sacrificed himself for his children.